# Crystal Report in ASP.NET has active expensive query report before all parameters entered

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.NET web application that uses Crystal Reports. I can run the report from within the application. For the reports that require input, when the dialog comes up from CR to input the parameters, an entry in the SQL Server database Activity Monitor "Active Expensive Queries" appears and does not go away until I kill the process. Is there some reason for this? Why is the query in the middle of being executed before the parameters have even been inputted?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to show us, what kind query Crystal Reports issues.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the parameters is dynamic (list of parameter values populated from the database) a query must be launched BEFORE the parameter dialog is displayed.